# Python Playwright API get hrefs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to get all hrefs listed in a series of html element blocks. I don't know how to refer to the href as a selector, and I know the hrefs all begin with "/wiki/".

I was wondering if there was a way to query the page for all hrefs that begin with this specific start to the href.

Comment: `href` is not a html element, it's an attribute within a link (a element), so you need to query for all links and then filter out those you don't want.

Comment: I am querying the correct areas and running it as a for loops, however, that doesn't help me with how to actually get the link of the href.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
hrefs_of_page = page.eval_on_selector_all("a[href^='/wiki/']", "elements => elements.map(element => element.href)")
```

which should work for your use-case. This will lookup for all the link tags which have a `href` attribute which starts with `/wiki`. Then on the browser side JavaScript gets evaluated which maps from an array of elements to the href attribute so a string array gets returned on the Python side.